# Suppressing all bottom padding of tabular cell

Tags: tables, spacing

Is it possible to totally suppress all bottom padding of a cell in the tabular environment?

Edit 2: As @Joseph Wright points out in the comments, I had stray linefeeds that were introducing extra space. So @gernot's answer is correct.

Edit: I've tried the answers, <s>but they don't always work</s>. For exampple:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newenvironment{resume}[1]
    {
        \noindent{\LARGE {\bf {#1}}} \\
        \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.2pt}}
        \vspace{-0.2cm} \\
    }
    {   
    }

\newcommand{\rsectionbegin}[1]{
        \renewcommand\arraystretch{0}
        \setbox\strutbox=\hbox{}
        \noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{3cm}p{12.5cm}}
        \noindent{\uppercase \nohyphens{#1}}
        &
    }
\newcommand{\rsectionend}{
        \end{tabular}
%       \\
    }

\newcommand{\rwherebegin}[2]{
        {\bf #1}, {#2} \par     
    }
\newcommand{\rwhereend}{
        \vspace{0.25cm}
    }

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcommand{\rrole}[2]{
        \vspace{0.15cm}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{9cm}R{3.05cm}}
        {\em {#1}} & {\bf {#2}}
        \end{tabular}
    }

\newcommand{\rwhat}[1]{
    {#1} \par
    }

\newcommand{\rskills}[1]{
    ({#1}) \par
    }

\newenvironment{ritemize}
    {
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.2cm]
    }
    {
        \end{itemize}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{resume}{L}
\rsectionbegin{A}
\rwherebegin{A}{A}
\rrole{A}{A}
\begin{ritemize}
\item[] A
\item[] A
\end{ritemize}
\rrole{A}{A}
\rwhereend
\rsectionend
\rsectionbegin{X}
Y
\rsectionend

\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

This still leaves space between Y and the preceding text. Should I be using a different environment or package altogether?

Comment: A MWE showing what is the problem would be nice.

Comment: I don't need a solution to a particular problem.

Comment: The question is pretty unclear in its current state. Please elaborate.

Comment: I want to ensure that there is no space between the lower edge of each cell and the lower edge of the content.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As I said, it's not a problem, it's a requirement. Like asking if the font can be set to bold. What do I send in, a table with some values i nit? It's a general question about every table constructed using tabular, not a specific example.

Comment: In the edit (which is likely best as a separate question) you have and _explicit_ `\vspace{0.25cm}` in `\rwhereend`. There are also _loads_ of stray spaces in the definitions as well as use of deprecated commands (not a spacing issue but still best fixed).

Comment: I edited down the example hastily, but even without the vspace the problem remains. The answer to my question seems to be "no", since I want to actively suppress padding, not just avoid specifying that it be there. In any case, I will open a new question defining my goal and asking for the right approach. I've marked the question answered.

Comment: @the.punisher I think there are some misconceptions involved. By doing what the answers propose the space in tabulars is indeed gone. But if you explicitly add space then you should expect it to become visible. Regarding your question about other packages: Have a look at cv classes, like `moderncv`.

Comment: As @Joseph Wright said, I had lots of stray linefeeds. I've now got it to display exactly as I'd intended. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given an ordinary `tabular` environment, you can set `\arraystretch` to `0` to eliminate the distance between cells. Adding space using the `\\` command ends up above an `\hline` (if present), i.e., it looks like space at the bottom of the cell. However, you can add struts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent0em
\parskip1ex
\begin{document}

Setting \verb"\arraystretch" to 0.

\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  A\\B\\C\\D\\E
\end{tabular}

Adding distance between rows using \verb"\\[...]" appears to end up
again below the cell.

\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
  A\\
  B\\[1ex]
  C\\[3ex]
  D\\
  E
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
  A\\\hline
  B\\[1ex]\hline
  C\\[3ex]\hline
  D\\\hline
  E
\end{tabular}

But we can insert an invisible rule that extends from the base line
upwards.

\newcommand\spaceabove[1]{\rule{0em}{#1}}
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
  A\\\hline
  B\\\hline
  \spaceabove{3ex}%
  C\\\hline
  \spaceabove{5ex}%
  D\\\hline
  E
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
  A\\\hline
  B\\\hline
  \spaceabove{3ex}%
  C\\\hline
  \spaceabove{5ex}%
  D\\\hline
  E
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Setting \arraystretch doesn't suppress all spacing. See edits to question.

Answer (score 3):

The LaTeX `tabular` construct inserts material at the start of cells to make sure they have a minimum height: this is set by the `\strutbox`. You can set that to an empty box to suppress this

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\setbox\strutbox=\hbox{}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \fbox{a}
  \end{tabular}%
}
\end{document}
```

although it's there to avoid different rows having different heights!